# Not to get listener OK click button in settings using AccessibilityService?

Tags: android, mouseclick-event, accessibilityservice

Hello i try to ask very clear so that everyone can get easily:-

i developed one app which do force stop programetically work fine 
**but** today i found one mobile LeEco which not performing this

my code is below

```
if (event.getSource() != null) {
    if (event.getPackageName().equals("com.android.settings")) {  
    AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();

    if (nodeInfo == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        // We can find button using button name or button id
        List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = nodeInfo
                .findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.android.settings:id/right_button");

        for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {

            node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
        }

        list = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("android:id/button1");
        for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
            node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);


            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Now** In LeEco i m unable to find **android:id/button1**  Is this any other ID android contain or any method which take all ID from that node list